# How to view the values of variables within $http.get using a service decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS $provide decorators it is possible to monkey patch a service to wrap, mock, or otherwise transform some method within the service without touching the service itself.

In my case, I am trying to watch the $http, for get requests that are larger than some size and when exceeded, break the request up into multiple requests.

For actually getting a hold of $http:

```
...
$provide.decorator('$http', function($delegate) {
    Object.size = function(obj) {
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
        }
        return size;
    };

    // monkey patching $http to break into multiple requests on the API, when 4096 KB are exceeded.
    var originalGet = $delegate.get;
    $delegate.get = function(args) {
        console.log("Get is called: ");
        console.log(args);
        //Can I view/manipulate/spy on $https own variables from here?

        return originalGet.apply(this, arguments);
    };


    return $delegate;


});
```

I believe I should be able to spy on the inner working of that function, but am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: What do you mean by "get requests which are larger than some size"?

Comment: I'm receiving request limit exceeded errors on an IIS server from sending GET requests that are too large, have too much information in them.  I'm attempting to break those requests into more manageable chunks by watching what http is doing and when the request is too large, send two requests instead.

Comment: Have an error handler on the request instead.

Comment: Are you saying that on .
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // Handler breaking up the request here?
  });       --    I should simply have a function that breaks up the request? From this, would I be able to tell that it was rejected based on the size of the request?

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. You could of course use decoration but that is for things that need to happen for every request in an app, I don't see the point here.

Comment: You have a GET request that is too large? Typically the request is just using an API with some sort of authentication, token, id, to request information.... are you meaning to POST something instead?

Comment: No, these are GET requests where the data in the header is becoming too large. This is requesting information but requires a complicated struct as input (basically a full hibernate query). Every once in a while, the hql is too big resulting in an error on IIS. On local machines it works fine.